# Computing a definite integral for the exponential of a polynomial.

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, indefinite-integrals

I'm looking for the most effective way to compute the following definite integral for a given *n*:

$\int_0^1e^{2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x^i-1}{i}}dx$

There are elementary solutions for *n* = 0 and *n* = 1, but I'm aware larger values of *n* can only be solved with non-elementary functions. For example, there is a solution for *n* = 2 using the imaginary error function.

My questions are:

1. Are there any non-elementary functions that could provide a generic solution for an arbitrary *n*.
2. Alternatively, is it perhaps possible to solve the integral in the form of a Taylor Series?
3. Alternatively, are there any tricks that could help me compute a definite integral faster for instances of this case?

In short, I'm trying to see what options I have for computing the above integral for arbitrary *n*, short of just using standard tools for computing the value of a definite integral.

Answer (score 3):

**Numerical integration**

According to the *Gauss–Kronrod quadrature method*:

$$
I\left(k_{max}\right) := \int_{-1}^1 \underbrace{\exp\left[2\sum_{k=1}^{k_{max}}\frac{\left(\frac{\tau + 1}{2}\right)^k - 1}{k}\right]\frac{1}{2}}_{:= f(\tau)}\,\text{d}\tau \approx \sum_{i = 1}^n f(t_i)\,w_i
$$

where the respective nodes and weights can be tabulated directly in *Wolfram Mathematica 12.2* as indicated in detail [on this page](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2019/04/14/stieltjes-polynomials-and-gauss-kronrod-quadrature/), or in other spreadsheets such as *Matlab* [in this other page](https://www.advanpix.com/2011/11/07/gauss-kronrod-quadrature-nodes-weights/).

As an example, fixed $k_{max} = 20$, already with the classic:

```
f[τ_] := Exp[2 Total[Table[(((τ + 1)/2)^k - 1)/k, {k, 20}]]] / 2
{n, prec} = {7, 10};

(*Gauss-Legendre quadrature*)
t = 2 NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[n, prec][[1]] - 1;
w = 2 NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[n, prec][[2]];
IG = Total[Table[f[t[[i]]] w[[i]], {i, n}]]

(*Gauss-Kronrod quadrature*)
t = 2 NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[n, prec][[1]] - 1;
w = 2 NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[n, prec][[2]];
IK = Total[Table[f[t[[i]]] w[[i]], {i, 2 n + 1}]]

Abs[IG - IK]
```

$$
I_{G7} = 0.034964534
\; \; \; \; \; \;
I_{K15} = 0.036094679
\; \; \; \; \; \;
\left|I_{G7} - I_{K15}\right| = 1.1 \cdot 10^{-3}
$$

the percentage error is around $1.6\%$, not bad! On the other hand, slightly increasing the nodes:

$$
I_{G15} = 0.036093780
\; \; \; \; \; \;
I_{K31} = 0.036094015
\; \; \; \; \; \;
\left|I_{G15} - I_{K31}\right| = 2.4 \cdot 10^{-7}
$$

the percentage error is practically zero and therefore $I \approx I_{K31}$, which is what is required.

---

**Curve fitting**

Keeping the number of nodes and the calculation precision unchanged, writing:

```
t = 2 NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[15, 10][[1]] - 1;
w = 2 NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[15, 10][[2]];

data1 = Table[f[τ_] := Exp[2 Total[Table[(((τ + 1)/2)^k - 1)/k, {k, kmax}]]] / 2;
              Total[Table[f[t[[i]]] w[[i]], {i, 31}]], {kmax, 0, 100}];

data2 = Table[0.74/(kmax + 1) + 0.26/(kmax + 1)^2, {kmax, 0, 100}];

ListPlot[{data1, data2}, AxesLabel -> {"kmax", "I(kmax)"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

we get:

[image]

from which it's clear that function estimates the integral very well (maximum error $0.5\%$).